# Why do checkboxes not get displayed in Google Chrome?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, google-chrome

I registered with Stack Overflow today to ask another question, but I had the problem that the accept terms checkbox is not displaying.

I have to inspect the page using the developer tools to find the hidden checkbox, at which point it might become visible or I resort to focussing it via developer tools and then pressing the spacebar to toggle it.

Really frustrating. Seems only to be with checkboxes.

Comment: sample code/link to problem site? What is the question?

Comment: Sounds like your browser has a problem, but probably not a question for SO. Maybe for meta.

Comment: I use chrome, and checkboxes --including on Stackoverflow-- work fine for me.  Is it possible that you've installed a [user stylesheet](http://userstyles.org/), or a "[user script](http://userscripts.org/)"?  Both can do things like hide checkboxes from you (and lots of other stuff too).

Comment: They do test on chrome, however I'm sending this to meta. Please update your question regarding the _exact_ Chrome version you are using and OS. Note, _beta_ builds of Chrome are _not_ supported.

Comment: Yeah Stack Overflow developers, why do you only test your .Net code on Mac and Firefox?

Comment: @TimPost OS is likely relevant in this case too, since my money is on it being [this long-running bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=3543).

Comment: @TimStone I edited my comment, but I think you nailed it.

Answer (score 1):

There hasn't been any activity on this post in 3 years, and the bug @TimStone linked to above has been closed, so I don't think there's anything to do here.  Also, the design of many, many things is different now.